# Undefined function in php

Tags: php, function

I wrote three methods in a class and one is calling another, but when I call the function outside through the object, it is showing an `undefined function` error for the second function.

Here's my code:

```
function resize_image(){

}

function image_resize(){
    $a = resize_image();
}
```

When I run this, it shows `resize_image()` as undefined. Here's the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function resize_image() in
>   /home/vacayge/public_html/Major/Alpha1/classes/cUserImages.php on line
>   2090

Comment: your given code is works perfectly no error displayed.

Comment: write full code so i can help you

Answer (score 3):

Using **`this`** you can access the function inside the class

put this code

```
$a = $this->resize_image();
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that when you call a function that belongs to an object you need to specify which object it belongs to. Similarly if you access a variable that belongs to an object then you need to specify which object it belongs to.

**Inside Object**

```
$this->my_func();
$this->my_var = 'foo';
```

**outside Object**

```
$my_obj->my_func();
$my_obj->my_var = 'foo';
```

**Static Stuff**(not required by your question but added for completeness)

```
MyClass::my_func();
MyClass::my_var = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 0):

**$this->resize_image();** this is the way to call a function from outside that function
http://query7.com/using-this-in-php check out for more details